# Are there any TC39 proposals to call a function if any argument is truthy?

Tags: javascript, syntax

So there's this stage 1 proposal for pipeline operator:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

`value |> func` which is essentially `func(value)`

What i'd like to do is turn the following code into a one liner:

```
const collision = howDidTheyCollide(entityA, entityB);
if (!!collision) handleCollision(entityA, entityB, collision);
```

I want syntax to call a function only if the argument is truthy. It doesn't need to involve the pipeline operator.

---

Supposing `?>` would only pipe the function if the value is truthy, I would imagine something like:

```
howDidTheyCollide(entityA, entityB) ?> handleCollision(entityA, entityB, ?)
```

If I had the functions returning an array of the arguments instead, then it could be:

```
[entityA, entityB] |> howDidTheyCollide ?> handleCollision
```

Another potential is something like `handleCollision(howDidTheyCollide(a, b)?)` where the ? represents `Don't call this function, unless this is truthy` The question mark could also be at the beginning of the function to represent `Don't call this function if ANY arguments are falsey`

EDIT: Lookng through the issues list of the pipeline operator and I found this great suggestion (same syntax too :p):
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/issues/159#issuecomment-554463586

Comment: For the time being, would something like: `howDidTheyCollide(entityA, entityB) |> (c => c && handleCollision(entityA, entityB, c));` work?

Comment: Yup! That's the best solution I've found thus far, but I'm hoping for a more concise version.